# .Net framework 4.5 is not available in windows features list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows

I already installed .net framework 4.6.1 in my machine but still there is no option for .net framework 4.0 or 4.5 features in Turn windows features on or off.

[image]

how i can enable features for .net framework 4.5 can any one help me to solve out this.

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Which version of Windows are you using?

Comment: i am using windows 7

Comment: That dialog will only show the version of the .NET framework that came bundled with the specific Windows release ([see here for more information](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2007/03/14/mailbag-what-version-of-the-net-framework-is-included-in-what-version-of-the-os/)).

Comment: Thanks christian so what i can do for add .net framework 4.5 in this list

Comment: Nothing. And you don't have to. If you manually installed (a newer version) of the .NET framework it will be "enabled" by that very act.

Comment: Okay thanks Christian...

Comment: @Nikhil.Patel : Have you solved this problem ?